# Splitting cells into multiple cells based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, regex

I have a column of data named "Code" that contains a value and a unit (for example 1KG). I am looking to split this column into two columns one: Code Value (ie. "1"), two: Code UOM (ie. "KG"). Where it gets complicated is there are multiple units in this column (KG, G, LB, OZ, etc.).

I was originally looking to at RegEx to do this, but I am new to RegEx and it seemed to get complicated a lot quicker than I expected.

Example data:

| Code |
| --- |
| 1KG |
| OZ |
| 50LB |
| 56G |
| 7.5LB |
| .5OZ |
| 4GM |
| 11.023LB |

```
uomorig_df = df['Code'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.search(r"\Boz|kg|lb|g|gm\w+"))
```

| Code Value | Code UOM |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | KG |
| 1 | OZ |

Comment: Just split using `(?<![a-zA-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z])` [Check here](https://regex101.com/r/VJD7jr/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
r = "(\d*\.?\d*)"

code_value = df.Code.str.extract("(\d*\.?\d*)")    
                                                   
code_UOM = df.Code.str.replace(r, '', regex = True)

new = pd.DataFrame(
    {"code value": code_value[0],
     "code UOM": code_UOM}
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  use [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) :

```
uomorig_df = df["Code"].str.extract(r"(?P<Code_Value>[\d.]+)?(?P<Code_UOM>\w+)")
```

​
Output :

```
print(uomorig_df)

  Code_Value Code_UOM
0          1       KG
1        NaN       OZ
2         50       LB
3         56        G
4        7.5       LB
5         .5       OZ
6          4       GM
7     11.023       LB
```

If you want to make *numeric* code-values, you can use :

```
uomorig_df = (
    df["Code"].str.extract(r"(?P<Code_Value>[\d.]+)?(?P<Code_UOM>\w+)")
        .astype({"Code_Value": "float"}) # or re-assign with `pd.to_numeric`
        # .fillna(1) # is this required ? If so, uncomment this line
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to use regular expressions, it looks like it shouldn't be *terribly* complicated.
The code value (what you want to be column 1) is represented by zero or more numbers, a decimal point, then zero or more numbers. From the python documentation, it looks like this regular expression should match your code value:

`[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*`

Which breaks down as follows:

`[0-9]` - matches any digit

`*` - the previous term is repeated zero or more times, so [0-9]* matches any sequence of numbers.

`\.?` - backslash means the next character should just be treated as a character to match, not have its special meaning, so this matches a decimal point. The question mark marks the previous character as optional, so in total \.? matches one or zero decimal points.

Then we just repeat our `[0-9]*` to recognize any digits after the decimal point.

If you know that the code UOM will never contain numeric digits or periods, you can simplify even further and recognize the code value as

```
[0-9.]*
```

Which recognizes any sequence of digits and/or decimal points, including nothing at all as in the second line of your table.

I don't have specific instructions for how to go from the regex to a complete solution, but if you wanted help with the expression I hope this makes sense!